# Laravel 5.1 "/" Route redirects to Default Apache Page. /index.php and all other route works fine

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, routes

I using LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04 hosted on DigitalOCean Droplet. My ip 1XX.XX.XX.101 redirects me to Default Apache2 page, while 1XX.XX.XX.101/index.php or 1XX.XX.XX.101/any-uri works fine. 
My laravel version is 5.1. Any help?

I have tried Directory Index.
**This works 1XX.XX.XX.101//** The double slash or any number of slashes more than 2 goes to index
My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.htm$
               default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml def$
               default.htm home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.h$
</IfModule>
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Conf File

    ServerName 104.131.48.27
    ServerAlias 104.131.48.27

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
<Directory /var/www/project/public>
    # Don't show directory index
   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

    # Allow .htaccess files
    AllowOverride All

    # Allow web access to this directory
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Error and access logs
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/raven.error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.access.log combined
```

Comment: what does index.php display?

Comment: @SamSolomon: 1XX.XX.XX.101/index.php works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was with my browser cache. Restarting machine resolved the issue.